# Run a command with different args everytime in Ansible playbook

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a command in Ansible so as to find the neighbors in my network:

```
- name: Get neighbors
  junos_rpc:
    rpc: "get-lldp-interface-neighbors"
    output: 'xml'
    args:
      interface_device: A
  register: net_topology
```

So my problem comes when in this task I need to loop over a list and give another arg for the interface_device and register the result also in another variable 'net_topology' every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- name: Get neighbors
  junos_rpc:
    rpc: "get-lldp-interface-neighbors"
    output: 'xml'
    args:
      interface_device: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - A
    - B
    - C
  register: net_topology
```

Once you modify your task like this, it will play three times: once for each element in my example loop. The variable `item` will get the value of the current element in the list.

You do not need to change your `register` variable: it will automatically be modified as explained in the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop):

> When you use `register` with a loop, the data structure placed in the variable will contain a `results` attribute that is a list of all responses from the module. This differs from the data structure returned when using `register` without a loop

So you can inspect all your results in a subsequent task by looping over `net_topology.results` which contains the list of individual results.

Comment: I also have a 2nd task and in that i am doing a loop like this: `- { path: "/rpc-reply/name", string: "{{ net_topology.results[].xml }}" } `.. So in the net_topology.results i want to get the field 'xml' from every object..But what i am doing is wrong.. i tried also this: "{{ net_topology.results[*].xml }}" but i am again wrong...how do i get from all results the item xml ? @Zeitounator

Comment: Loop on `net_topology.results`, what you want to get will be in  `item.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did something similar with the above, but i just passed my list with a different way:

```
- name: building network topology
  junos_rpc:
    rpc: "get-lldp-interface-neighbors"
    output: 'xml'
    args:
      interface_device: "{{item}}"
  loop:
    "{{my_list}}"
  register: net_topology
```

And this is actually the same as doing this also:

```
- name: building network topology
  junos_rpc:
    rpc: "get-lldp-interface-neighbors"
    output: 'xml'
    args:
      interface_device: "{{item}}"
  with_items:
    "{{my_list}}"
  register: net_topology
```

I must say that my initial mistake was the identation of the loop, because it was placed inside the junos_rpc and by doing this I could not get any result !!!